# Differential equation for the family of curves $f(x,y)=c$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

My books states that:

For the family of curves $f(x,y)=0$ the differential equations can be written as $df=0$ or

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy = 0$

I don't really get this. How can we "mix" partial derivatives with normal derivatives?

Comment: Do you know the meaning of $df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: what is wrong with this question ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust umm no. Is that true for every $f(x,y)?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Lack of context.

Comment: @jonsnow: if you have heard about partial derivatives, you should have heard of the total differentials. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative#The_total_derivative_as_a_differential_form (sorry, this reference is not the clearest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation $f(x,y)=0$ defines a *single* curve in the $(x,y)$-plane, and the equation $$f(x,y)=c\tag{1}$$ with $c$ a "parameter variable" defines a *family* of curves, whereby the members of this family are "numbered" by the values of $c$.

As long as you don't know what $dx$, $dy$, $df$ mean you can bring ODEs into the picture by saying that you want your curves to be graphs $y=\phi_c(x)$ of as yet unknown  functions $\phi_c$. In the case of $(1)$ this means that $\phi_c$ satisfies the following identity:
$$f\bigl( x, \>\phi_c(x)\bigr)=c\qquad(a<x<b)\ ,\tag{2}$$
wereby the exact domain $\>]a,b[\>$ has to be determined at the end. Since $(2)$ is an identity in $x$ we may differentiate with respect to $x$ and obtain the condition
$$f_{.1}(x,\phi_c(x))\cdot 1+f_{.2}(x,\phi_c(x))\cdot\phi_c'(x)\equiv0\qquad(a<x<b)\ ,\tag{3}$$
where ${}_{.1}$ means that we have differentiated the given function $f$ with respect to its first variable, and similarly ${}_{.2}$. The equation $(3)$ can rewritten as ODE for the unknown function $\phi_c$ as follows:
$$\phi_c'(x)=-{f_{.1}(x,\phi_c(x))\over f_{.2}(x,\phi_c(x))}\ .\tag{4}$$
Now one usually denotes the unknown solution function in an ODE usually by $y$, so that $(4)$ finally appears as
$$y'=-{f_{.1}(x,y)\over f_{.2}(x,y)}\ .\tag{5}$$
The RHS in $(5)$ is an explicitly given (or easily computable) function of $(x,y)$. Note that $(5)$ does not contain the letter $c$ at any place; hence this ODE describes *every* single family curve of $(1)$ at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f$ is differentiable and that $y$ is a differentiable solution of the equation $f(x,y)=c.$ Hence

$$f(x,y(x))=c.$$

By the chain rule we get

$$\frac{ \partial f}{\partial x}(x,y(x))+\frac{ \partial f}{\partial y}(x,y(x)) \cdot y'(x)=0.$$